# Why is this Binary search returning as NoneL

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, search

I made this recursive binary search algorithm which cuts the list in half every time and I don't understand why it is returning null.

```
def recursionSearch(target, numlist):
    if len(numlist) == 0:
        return -1
    mid = len(numlist)//2
    if numlist[mid] == target:
        return mid
    elif(target < numlist[mid]):
        recursionSearch(target,numlist[:mid])
    else:
        recursionSearch(target, numlist[mid+1:])
```

Supposed to return index of the target

Comment: Is it returning `null`, or is it returning `-1`?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `return` to your recursive calls:

`return recursionSearch(target,numlist[:mid])`

Without those you're executing the search but discarding the results.

Just as a tip, you should debug things like this by exploring what your program flow is like. If you don't want to use an actual debugger, you can just insert `print` statements at relevant program points to learn what's getting run and with what values.